# Abstract class without any abstract method Vs declaring it as class

Tags: java, class, abstract-class

can someone tell me when to have a abstract class without any abstract method in it Vs declaring it as concrete class? Please provide some intutive example for understanding it in a better way :)

Answer (score 1):

Abstract classes cannot be instanciated, no matter of how many abstract methods they have:

```
abstract class AbstractFoo {}
class Foo {}

class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(); // legit
        AbstractFoo foo = new AbstractFoo(); // Error: AbstractFoo is abstract; 
                                             // cannot be instantiated
    }
}
```

Declaring a class without abstract methods as abstract makes sense if you don't want your users to use it directly, but just to inherit its functionalities

Comment: @Oneiros the question is about when there are NO abstract methods

Comment: apologies, initially it looked like the answer is applicable when there are abstract methods.

Answer (score 0):

It's about OOD (object oriented design)
D principle from [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)): [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle)
We should use abstraction in our references instead of concreat classes.

Also [GoF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_Patterns) says aboud Dependency Idjection. Which means "following as advantages of interfaces over implementation". Using this approach you always can change implementation and keep using old abstraction (abstract class or interface)

Answer (score 0):

The only difference between the two is that you can't actually create instances of the abstract class. It's not very common that you'd have implementations for all methods, but still wanted to prevent instantiation.. But maybe one example would be if you wanted to represent things with singletons, where each is of its own class, maybe tables in a DB:

```
abstract class DbTable { DbTable(String nameInDb) { ... } /* +methods */ }

class DbProduct extends DbTable { DbProduct() { super("products") } }
class DbCategory extends DbTable { DbCategory() { super("categories") } }

static final DbProduct PRODUCT = new DbProduct();
static final DbCategory CATEGORY = new DbCategory();
```

Now even though DbTable may already implement all the methods, the design makes you not want to instantiate it without subclassing, and making it abstract helps enforce that rule..